# cassandra kafka connect source and eventual consistency

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, eventual-consistency, apache-kafka-connect

I am thinking about using Kafka connect to stream updates from Cassandra to a Kafka topic. The existing connector from StreamReactor seems to use a timestamp or uuidtimestamp to extract new changes since the last poll. The value of the timestamp is inserted using now() in the insert statement. The connector then saves the maximum time is received last time.

Since Cassandra is eventually consistent I am wondering what actually happens when doing repeated queries using a time range to get new changes. Is there not risk to miss rows inserted into Cassandra because it "arrived late" to the node queried when using WHERE create >= maxTimeFoundSoFar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it might happen that you have newer data in front of your "cursor" when you already went on with processing if you are using consistency level one for reading and writing, but even if you use higher consistency you might run into "problems" depending on the setup that you have. Basically there are a lot of things that can go wrong.

You can increase the chances of not doing this by using an old cassandra formula `NUM_NODES_RESPONDING_TO_READ + NUM_NODES_RESPONDING_TO_WRITE > REPLICATION_FACTOR` but since you are using `now()` from cassandra the node clocks might have millisecond offsets between them so you might even miss data if you have high frequency data. I know of some systems where people are actually using raspberry pi's with gps modules to keep the clock skew really tight :)

You would have to provide more about your use case but in reality yes you can totally skip some inserts if you are not "careful" but even then there is no 100% guarantee other then you process the data with some offset that would be enough for the new data to come in and settle.

Basically you would have to keep some moving time window in the past and then move it along plus making sure that you don't take into account anything newer than the let's say last minute. That way you are making sure the data is "settling".

I had some use cases where we processed sensory data that would came in with multiple days of delay. On some projects we simply ignored it on some the data was for reporting on the month level so we always processed the old data and added it to reporting database. i.e. we kept a time window 3 days back in history.

It just depends on your use case.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So I was not totally wrong in my assumption. I was thinking of publishing the data from Cassandra to Kafka to push the data to other consumers "real-time". I don't really want to lose data so my approach might not be ideal